# which method in ASP.NET life-cycle is only called once? It is not fired during postback

Tags: asp.net

Can we avoid using

If (!Postback) {.....code runs once....}

in Page_load()

Answer (score 5):

I'm not particularly "hot" on ASP.NET events, but don't you think if there were a better approach (within the normal ASP.NET model) than the usual "`if (!Postback)`" one, everyone would already be using it?

I suspect there may be *some* cunning way of avoiding it, but only as "clever" code which will make it harder to maintain.

A single `if` statement isn't exactly horrendous...

(I'm not a big fan of the ASP.NET model to start with, admittedly... but if you're already within that model, there are worse things to contend with than this.)

Answer (score 1):

This one is called only once:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
```

Google "[global.asax](http://www.google.lv/search?hl=lv&source=hp&q=global.asax&btnG=Google+mekl%C4%93%C5%A1ana&meta=&aq=f&oq=)" for more info.

Comment: OP didn't mentioned the life cycle of page or an application but have a look at thread description. He/she is talking about page_load() and IsPostBack (PostBack).

Comment: I just wanted to accent importance of question quality. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to happen the event not to occur in subsequest postbacks you have to write code in

```
if ( !IsPostBack )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, because the web is stateless and so each ASP.NET page needs to be loaded each time it is being requested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event/method that you can hook up code in page life cycle that runs once. Every time the page instance passes through the same steps. That is the model.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an event that is only called once. In ASP.NET MVC you can distinguish between GET and POST using the `AcceptVerbs` attribute but that is just akin to `IsPostBack`, looking at the `Request` object.

[`Init`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(VS.71).aspx) is called before any `ViewState` is loaded so that might help, and the `LoadViewState` method is only called when a ViewState is loaded.

This is a simplification of the above link:

> OnInit: 1
>   LoadViewState: 2
>   CreateChildControls: 3
>   OnLoad: 4
>   ShowButton: 5
>   OnPreRender: 6
>   Render: 7
>   OnUnload: 8

Number 3 can occur at any point in the chain.